# How to change key action and disable system key function?

Tags: android

**
I want to change key to another key, like when I press green key(KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN) it will change to g key(KEYCODE_G).

And want to disable open explorer system key function.
If didn't use root to edit system key file, is it possible?
**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
     if (keyCode == KEYCODE_EXPLORER) {         
         return true;
     }
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN) {          
         keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G;
     }
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_RED) {            
         keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R;
     }
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_YELLOW) {         
         keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y;
     }

     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) {           
         keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y;           


     }
     Log.d("Test", "Short");
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    

}
```